# Query to handle the dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Background**
Result set should look like

```
Type     Amount   Remaining_Credit   Transaction_date    expiry_date
Credit   12000    12000              10/11/2019          12/11/2019
Debit    -7500    4500               11/11/2019
Credit   4000     8500               11/11/2019
Credit   1000     5000               13/11/2019
```

(4500 is removed from remaining_credit because 12000 had an expiry_date for 12/11/2019)

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? You tagged your question with exclusive tags.

Comment: I'm building my script on sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following methods:

1. Case expression to set `Amount` to `0` when it's expired

```
CASE 
  WHEN (ISNULL(EXPIRY_DATE, DATEADD(DAY,1, GETDATE() ))) >= GETDATE()
     THEN AMOUNT
  ELSE 0 
END
```

```
CASE 
  WHEN EXPIRY_DATE IS NULL OR  EXPIRY_DATE >= GETDATE()
     THEN AMOUNT
  ELSE 0 
END
```

2. Filter-out expired rows

```
Where (ISNULL(EXPIRY_DATE, DATEADD(DAY,1, GETDATE() ))) >= GETDATE()
```

**Full Script - Updated**

```
Create table #Wallet
(Account_ID varchar(3),
 TransID int,
 TransDate datetime,
 ExpriryDate datetime,
 Amount float,
 TranType varchar (10),
 Credit float,
 Debit float )
 go 

 Insert into #Wallet 
 (Account_ID, TransID, TransDate, ExpriryDate, Amount, TranType, Credit,Debit)
 values 
 ('def', (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))/10000), DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()), DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 500, 'CR', 500, 0 ),
 ('def', (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))/10000), DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()), null, 400, 'CR', 500, 0 ),
 ('def', (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))/10000), DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()), null, -300, 'DR', 0, 300 )
 go


 --- Filter out expired rows -----------------------------------------------------------------
 SELECT TranType, 
        Amount, 
        TransDate, 
        SUM (Amount) over (partition by Account_ID order by TransDate) ReminingBalance,
        ExpriryDate
 FROM #Wallet
 Where (ISNULL(ExpriryDate, DATEADD(DAY,1, GETDATE() ))) >= GETDATE ()
 go


 --- Include expired rows with 0 Value -----------------------------------------------------------------

 SELECT TranType, 
        Amount, 
        TransDate, 
        SUM (NewAmount) over (partition by Account_ID order by TransDate) ReminingBalance,
        ExpriryDate
FROM 
        (SELECT *, (CASE WHEN ExpriryDate IS NULL OR  ExpriryDate >= GETDATE () THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as NewAmount FROM #Wallet) AS T1
go

--Drop table #Wallet
```